# SQL Query Report Writing

Tags: mysql, sql

I provided the ERD showing all the Tables and their info.  How would I go about writing an SQL query for this report? Let me know if any other details are needed or if the ERD is sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date(s.showtime) as date
    , s.showtime
    , c.channelnumber
    , p.progname
    , p.proglength 
    , su.suppliername
FROM program as p left join schedule as s on p.progid = s.programid 
left join channel as c on s.channelid = c.channelid 
left join supplier as su on p.supplierid = su.supplierid
```

your schedule table has many pk and your structure is not according to normalized form. better restructure it 
thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if that works.  If we need to restructure that table, then I'll try to figure it out.  This is a group project I'm doing in an SQL class, and unfortunately half the team isn't doing anything.  So a lot of this has been left on me and I am totally brand new to SQL.  I was doing ok up to this point, but this week has me a bit lost.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I cannot get this to work at all.  It gives me an error at line one, saying missing expression. The Schedule table is pretty much just being used to join other tables for reporting purposes.  How would you suggest restructuring it?